# MongoDB Atlas triggers don't work with Neo4j driver

Tags: javascript, mongodb, neo4j, mongodb-atlas

My goal is to create an Atlas triggers to synchronize my MongoDB database with a Neo4j (Aura) database. The function I wrote works fine on my computer, however, when called by the trigger it throws this error:

```
TypeError: Configured resolver function should either return an array of addresses or a Promise resolved with an array of addresses.Each address is '<host>:<port>'. Got: [object Promise]
```

This is the function:

```
(async () => {
  const neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");

  const uri = "neo4j+s://d3dc4645.databases.neo4j.io";
  const user = "neo4j";
  const password = "...";

  const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password));
  const session = driver.session();

  const id = "TEST"
  
  const writeQuery = `MERGE (p1:User {id:$id })`;
  await session.writeTransaction((tx) => tx.run(writeQuery, { id }));
  await driver.close();
})();
```

In the trigger it is like this (this doesn't work):

```
exports = async function(changeEvent) {

  const neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");

  const uri = "neo4j+s://d3dc4645.databases.neo4j.io";
  const user = "neo4j";
  const password = "...";

  const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password));
  const session = driver.session();

  const id = "TEST"
  
  const writeQuery = `MERGE (p1:User {id:$id })`;
  await session.writeTransaction((tx) => tx.run(writeQuery, { id }));
  await driver.close();
};
```

I honestly have no idea what the problem is. I can guess that it derives from some incompatibility of that dependence or in any case, is linked to the way in which promises are managed.
What am I doing wrong?

It's still a limiting problem for me...

**Update** after the reply of @NBekelman.

I have already tried in the following days to change the code but unfortunately, the error message is always the same.

```
exports =  function(changeEvent) {
  [...]
  
  const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password));
  const session = driver.session({ defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.WRTIE });

  
  console.log(session); // <-- so far so good
  
  
  const writeQuery = `MERGE (p1:User {id:"TEST" })`;

  session.run(writeQuery) // <-- error
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .then(() => session.close()); 

  
  driver.close();
};
```

Comment: This question was tagged as Realm but it doesn't appear to have anything to do with MongoDB Realm mobile platform. Does it?

Comment: You are right, I got confused

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a Promise but the function you are using expect to a value (by the error, the type should be `<host>:<port>`;

Also I think you should use

```
module.exports = ... // default exports
exports.handler = ... // named exports
```

[module exports nodejs](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

Publish the consumer of this function for more help if needed.

Comment: The way the function is exported is the correct way for Atlas and in fact, that is not the problem since the function runs correctly. The error is thrown in this line `await session.writeTransaction((tx) => tx.run(writeQuery, { id }));`  and I have also tried unsuccessfully to replace it with other approaches like these https://adamcowley.co.uk/javascript/using-the-neo4j-driver-with-nodejs/   And again, the function works great locally, but not on Atlas

Comment: In the error you published it says: ```Got: [object Promise]```. So it got to be a problem in promises. I looked deeper, for the sake of test - can you change the code to work with .then(s). I think it may be that [atlas not working with async await](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/atlas-triggers-not-working-with-async-await/132494).